# jquery - using .load and .after together

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to write some jquery to dynamically update the rows of a table, not affecting the header "th" parts. I can load the whole table or I can replace the the table rows with html, but I can't load the table rows from (say) a .php page. This is important as my "th" rows have my drop-down selectors in them. I don't want to have to re-create them on the php page.

This is my code snippet:

```
var trigger_value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
$( "#datatable tr:first").siblings().remove(); 
$( "#datatable tr:first").load("datatableload.php", 
{category: trigger_value} ) ;
```

I can replace the .load with a .after but I just get the text "/cms/sq-datatable.php" in my table, which is predicable as thats what .after is expecting.

I hope this makes sense.
Jon

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the php result into a variable, and then using .append to your table
edit-- probably keep using after, but change to last instead of first, but load from variable

Comment: Thanks Ben....append adds .html to the table. How do I make it call the .php page? - Sorry, just worked out what you mean.

Comment: use an ajax call to have the php results stored into a variable. get for instance

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var trigger_value = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
$( "#datatable tr:first").siblings().remove(); 
$( "<div>").load("datatableload.php", 
{category: trigger_value}, function(){
     $( "#datatable").append($(this).html());
}) ;
```